# Quicksort implementation

Tags: algorithm, ruby, sorting, quick-sort

I put together this implementation after playing around with various partitioning- and pivot-strategies, and it runs fine. I wrote this off a version which seemed a bit different from the majority of implementations, so I'm curious on what you guys think. It works and handles duplicates.

```
def quicksort(a, min=0, max=a.length-1)
  if min < max
    index = partition(a, min, max)
    quicksort(a, min, index-1)
    quicksort(a, index+1, max)
  end
end

def partition(a, l, r)

  m=(l+r)/2
  piv = a[m]
  a[m], a[r] = a[r], a[m]

  cur = l
  for i in l..r-1

    if a[i] <= piv
      a[i], a[cur] = a[cur], a[i]
      cur+=1
    end
  end
  a[cur], a[r] = a[r], a[cur]

  return cur

end
```

Comment: It's amusing just how terse Quicksort can be in Ruby.  For a functional (that is, not in-place) version of Quicksort that is just a few lines, see [this page on Ward's wiki](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?QuickSortInRuby)

Answer (score 5):

You code looks nice, my main problem with it is **naming**:

Don't use single letters as member names, unless they are trivial. I couldn't figure out what `l` and `r` stand for until I read your code a couple of times (length? range?).

Even more so, don't *ever* use the letter `l` as a variable name - it is much too similar to `1`, and is notoriously known to obfuscate code.

**Don't re-use too familiar names for different purposes** - [`partition`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) is a well known method in ruby enumerables. Using this name for your code, especially when it involves arrays is *very* confusing. Don't do that. Call it `reorder_partition` or `pivot_partition`.

**Expressiveness goes a long way** - `a[l], a[r] = a[r], a[l]` works perfectly, but is hard to read, a much more readable way would be if you had a helper method `swap(a, l, r)`. Even better might look to implement it into `Array` [`a.swap!(l, r)`](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/swap-elements-array-ruby)

**Use the power of ruby** - instead of `l..r-1`, use [non-inclusive range operator](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_ranges.htm) - `l...r`

So, my version may look a little more verbose, but I believe it is much more readable. It did teach me a lot about quicksort :-)

```
def quicksort(array, min=0, max=array.length-1)
  if min < max
    index = reorder_partition(array, min, max)
    quicksort(array, min, index-1)
    quicksort(array, index+1, max)
  end
end

def reorder_partition(array, left_index, right_index)
  middle_index = (left_index + right_index)/2
  pivot_value = array[middle_index]

  array.swap!(middle_index, right_index)

  less_array_pointer = left_index

  (left_index...right_index).each do |greater_array_pointer|
    if array[greater_array_pointer] <= pivot_value
      array.swap!(greater_array_pointer, less_array_pointer)
      less_array_pointer+=1
    end
  end

  array.swap!(less_array_pointer, right_index)

  return less_array_pointer
end

class Array
  def swap!(a,b)
    self[a], self[b] = self[b], self[a]
    self
  end
end
```

Comment: +1. Just some comments: 1) I'd use `each` instead of `for` (more idiomatic). 2) Some spaces seem to be missing (for example on `middle_index=(...`

Answer (score 2):

## Integer Overflow

I'm not very confident with ruby but I'm assuming this is integer arithmetic (otherwise you could have a floating point index, which doesn't make sense):

```
  m=(l+r)/2
```

If it indeed is integer arithmetic you will have an integer overflow if you're dealing with large arrays.

You should implement it as:

```
 m = l + (r - l)/2;
```

which will not overflow for any `0 <= l <= r`.